# Matching file extensions inside content with grep ('*.log' is an error)

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to search each line to see which lines have **any_filename.log**

The below codes aren't working

```
find . -print | xargs grep -i *.log
find . -print | xargs grep -i "*.log"
find . -print | xargs grep -i '*.log'
```

does anyone know the right code?

thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need the `*` at all; it doesn't do anything useful here. In regex syntax (as used by grep), `*` means "0 or more of the immediately preceding character". When there *is* no preceding character, it is thus a syntax error.

By contrast, `.` in a regex means "match any single character". If you want to match a period, you need to escape it or put it inside a character class, like so:

```
find . -exec grep -i -e '[.]log' -- /dev/null '{}' +
```

If the line needs to *end with* `.log`, by contrast, anchor the match with a `$`:

```
find . -exec grep -i -e '[.]log$' -- /dev/null '{}' +
```

---

Notes:

- `*.log` is glob syntax. `[.]log$` is an equivalent pattern in regex (regular expression) syntax. These are two very different languages.
- `find ... | xargs ...` is buggy (fails with filenames containing spaces, quotes, literal backslashes, etc) unless `-print0` is used in `find`, and `-0` is used with `xargs`. Both of these are non-POSIX extensions, so it's better to use the POSIX-compliant `-exec ... {} +` action in `find` to get the xargs behavior of running as few subprocesses as possible with names given literally.
- The `grep ... -- /dev/null` idiom services two purposes: Passing `/dev/null` ensures that `grep`'s defaults are those it uses when passed at least two files, even if `find` only invoked that particular `grep` instance with only a single filename. The `--` flag, by contrast, ensures that all subsequent filenames are treated as names, not as flags; it's not strictly necessary when used with `find` in this manner (as all arguments will be preceded with `./`, thus not potentially looking like optional arguments), but is good practice nonetheless.

Comment: great! thank you.that solves it, but how do I look for all files that contain *storage*[.]log     if that makes any sense?

Comment: That would be `storage.*[.]log$`. Regexes are unanchored by default, so there's no need for a wildcard at the beginning -- if you wanted to force a string to match only if it was at the beginning, you'd have to put a `^` in front of it.

Comment: thank you very much. I think i need to go look at regexes closer to make life easier. never realized they were called regexes. cheers :)

Comment: Note that there's more than one regex syntax. Standard grep supports either BRE ("basic", used by default) or ERE ("extended"; enabled with `grep -E`); many newer languages and tools use derivatives of PCRE ("perl-compatible") instead, which has modern conveniences but less predictable performance: Some of those modern conveniences are impossible to implement with reasonable guarantees on worst-case performance, whereas BRE or ERE can be implemented in a way that will always be fast.